# Any way to manipulate wordpress plugin options within my theme function file?

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

I am trying to see if I could change a plugin's admin options within my theme functions?

For example, the plugin allows you to upload a logo.  Can I filter it somehow to remove that option from the plugin within my theme function.php?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the plugin is hookable. Most of the time the answer to that question is no, unfortunately. I would approach the plugin author regarding that.

Comment: well i was thinking since the options need to be added through the wp admin menu action, there was a way to filter out certain options...